# 411 Error in Loadrunner

Tags: load-testing, performance-testing, loadrunner

I am running a webservice which has "GET" method in it, but I am facing "HTTP Status Code=411(The remote server returned an error (411) Length Required)" error. How do I rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

try adding a header with length information in it.